# Entity Framework cant load list 2 levels down

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following Model structure:

Skill
Intents (foreign key to SkillId)
Utterances (foreign key to IntentId)
Slots (foreign key to UtteranceId)

**Intent Model**

```
public class Intent
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }    
        [ForeignKey("Skill")]
        public int? SkillId { get; set; }    
        public string Description { get; set; }           
        public virtual Skill Skill { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Utterance> Utterances { get; set; }
    }
```

**Utterance Model**

```
   public class Utterance
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }    
        [ForeignKey("Intent")]
        public int IntentId { get; set; }
        public string Utterancetext { get; set; }            
        public virtual Intent Intent { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Slot> Slots { get; set; }
    }
```

**Slot Model**

```
public class Slot
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Utterance")]
    public int UtteranceId { get; set; }
    public string SlotValue { get; set; }
    public SlotDataTypes SlotDataType { get; set; }        
    public virtual Utterance Utterance { get; set; }
}
```

**Entity framework fluent API**

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Intent>()
            .HasOptional(i => i.Skill)
            .WithMany(sk => sk.Intents)
            .HasForeignKey(i => i.SkillId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Utterance>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Intent)
            .WithMany(x => x.Utterances)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.IntentId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Slot>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Utterance)
            .WithMany(x => x.Slots)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UtteranceId);
```

In my data access service, i have a method which should get Intents > Utterances > Slots.

```
var intents = ctx.Intents.Include(x => x.Utterances).Include("Utterances.Slots").ToList(); //<-- utterances are populated, slots count is 0
var utterances = ctx.Utterances.Include(x => x.Slots).ToList(); // utterances are populated, slots are populated
var slots = ctx.Slots.ToList(); // slots are populated

        return intents;
```

The first call is what i need, to get me all the intents, their related utterances, and the utterances related slots. The utterances are populating but the slots are always zero, even though there definitely are slots in the db, and the second call proves that because if i just go straight for Utterances, and include the Slots, i get slots back.

Where am i going wrong with the Intent navigation all the way down to Slots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to write:

```
var intents = ctx.Intents.Include(x => x.Utterances.Select(u => u.Slots)).ToList();
```

Calling `Select` compose additional includes after including a collection property.